# javascript validation for email format accepting incorrect email format @abcd.com.gmail,

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate email address in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

I have to do validation for Email format, I am using the CODE below line to restrict Special Characters.

```
onkeypress="return AlphaNumericBox(event,this,'@._);"
```

But now the Problem is I don have any proper validation for the exact format for example its also accepting text like `" @abcd.com.gmail,.. "` Is there any javascript validation for this? 
any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: There is a far greater chance that a user will enter an invalid or incorrect e–mail address that passes the rules for an e–mail address format than enter an invalid format. The best (i.e. only reliable) solution to checking that a user has entered their e–mail address correctly is to send an e–mail to that address and see if they respond.

Comment: @sym3tri: For urls in comments use next markup: `[ text ] ( url )` (w/out spaces of course), e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: the response are here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript/1373724#1373724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function CheckEmail(address){
    address=address.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, "");
    var reg=/([\w._-])+@([\w_-])+(\.([\w_-])+){1,2}/;
    var matcharr=reg.exec(address);
    if(matcharr!=null){
        if(matcharr[0].length==address.length){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

eg:
var sVal=" t.st@gmail.com.cn ";
var sVal2=" t.st@gmail.com.cn.abc ";
console.log(CheckEmail("name@server.com"));    //outpus true
console.log(CheckEmail("@server.com"));   //outpus false
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use this function. I've tested it many times.

```
function validateEmail (emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Now, you can easily validate any email address:

```
var isValid = validateEmail('name@server.com'); // returns true;
isValid = validateEmail('@server.com'); // returns false;
```